# Post Type Description for 'Posts'

Tags: custom-post-types

On the site I'm currently developing I am using 'Custom Post Type UI' to manage my custom post types.

Within this I can manage the description for any of the new custom post types that I have created.

How would I go about editing the description of the default 'posts' post type?

I am outputting this description under the heading in each section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `global $wp_post_types` to edit the description for example:

```
add_action('init' , 'edit_post_description');
function edit_post_description(){
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['post'] ->description = 'type your description here...';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know of anyway to manage it through the dashboard? (via a plugin?). I'd ideally like to be able to give a client control over it.

Comment: you can create an admin panel http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus